# Low water pressure and oil pressure at the same time

Tags: oil, cooling-system, camaro

I have a 98 Camaro and I would like to know what's going on with my car. It is currently experiencing of loss of water pressure and oil pressure at the same time, and then it starts knocking as if its about to cut off. What are the possible causes of these symptoms?

Comment: Welcome to the site. How did you determine that water and oil pressures are low? Did you measure them with a pressure gauge?

Comment: Does the 98 Camaro even have a coolant pressure gauge? I can't think of a single car that has one stock.

Comment: What engine is in your Camaro? And @Ben ... no a Camaro *does not have a coolant pressure gauge*. I'm wondering if the OP is actually meaning something else?

Comment: And what RPM is it running when it behaves this way?